# Calculate probability of occurrence from multiple grids

Tags: raster, r

I generate a lot of spatial grid files and I want to calculate the probability that a certain threshold isn't exceeded. In this example here I want to see what's the probability of each cell that the value is equal or smaller than 0. I do this by counting the occurrences and divide them by the number of rasters involved. This code works, but this looks terribly bloated. Is there a way to make this more efficient, especially with the aim of doing this for hundreds of really large raster maps? (and I need to work with SpatialGridDataFrame, not with raster files from `raster` package, thus the conversion)

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
seeds <- c(2013,2014,2016)
n <- 0
pfail <- matrix(0,5,5)
pfail <- raster(pfail)
pfail <- as(pfail, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')
for (i in seeds) {
  set.seed(i)
  n <- n+1
  xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),5,5)
  rast <- raster(xy)
  sgdf <- as(rast, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')
  rast <- paste("rast",n,sep="")
  assign(rast,sgdf)
  for (j in 1:length(sgdf)) {
    pfail[j] <- ifelse(sgdf$layer[j]<=0,pfail$layer[j]+1,pfail$layer[j])
  }
}
pfail$layer <- sapply(pfail$layer, function(x) x/length(seeds))
```

Comment: You can skip `ifelse` merely by summing the values of `sgdf$layer[j] <= 0`.  But apart from that, what's inefficient about this?  If the component rasters really are large, you won't be able to hold them all in RAM at once, so at a minimum you have to read each one from some dataset or compute it *ab initio*--and that operation is likely to be the time-limiting one.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, insightful as ever. I still have issues using for loops in R as everyone seems to go crazy when this is used instead of apply, sapply etc.

Comment: Just some quick reactions concerning `for` loops.  First, using `for` instead of some other construct to loop over expensive operations (such as processing an entire grid in some way) makes no practical difference.  Second, they can be surprisingly fast anyway.  The advantages of the apply* family are part conceptual and part in their potential for automatic parallel execution. Another (which I have found convenient) is that apply* automatically and dynamically allocate the output list or array for you.  If there is no such output, often a `for` loop is a good choice.